# Need 3 regex for not allowing number, not allowing alphabets and not allowing special character

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create angular js directive for input field which will be configurable to allow numbers or alphabets or special character. Example

HTML
`<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.inputField" is-alphabets-allowed="false"
 is-numbers-allowed="true"is-special-characters-allowed="false"`

DIRECTIVE

```
angular.module('forms').directive('inputFieldConstraint', nputFieldConstraint);
InputFieldConstraint.$inject = ['constraintsService'];

function InputFieldConstraint(constraintsService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            isAlphabetsAllowed: '=',
            isNumbersAllowed: '=',
            isSpecialCharactersAllowed: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, ele) {
            $(ele).on('input', function () {
                var test = $(ele).val().replace(/[^a-bA-Z]/g, '');
                $(ele).val(test);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest best practice to create the directive and which regular expression I should use for these 3 cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach - during the `link()`, use the scope variables to build a single regex and then apply a new `ng-pattern` directive programmatically:

```
    link: function (scope, ele) {
         const allowedClasses = [];
         const { isAlphabetsAllowed, isNumbersAllowed, isSpecialCharactersAllowed } = scope;

         if (isAlphabetsAllowed) allowedClasses.push("[a-zA-Z]");
         if (isNumbersAllowed) allowedClasses.push("/d+");
         if (isSpecialCharactersAllowed) allowedClasses.push("\\^\\$\\(\\)");

         const regexString = allowedClasses.join("");
         scope.regex = new RegExp(regexString, 'g');

         $(ele).attr('ng-pattern', 'regex'); //references our new scope.regex
    }
```

Note that you'd also need to update the value of `scope.regex` if the `isAlphabetsAllowed` etc ever changed, so you might need a `$scope.watch()` or similar.

Also, in order to make sure that this operation happens before `ng-pattern` directive fires, you'll need to ensure that the priority of your directive is higher than the priority of `ng-pattern`, which is `0`, so I'd set the `priority` to `1` to ensure you go first.

ng-pattern documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: Thanks @Duncan, for the answer. In our application angular ( 1.3.15) has been used so I can't use ng-pattern. Is there any other best approach can we used for this scenario.

Comment: The best you can probably do then is try to base your code on the implementation of ng-pattern. Source code is here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L89